# Making clickable regions in an image in android

Tags: android, widget

Is there an example somewhere of how to make different irregular shaped parts of an image clickable? For example the different buttons in this image?

[image: A sample dpad image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think something like this is what you'll want to look at

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape